# Performance degradation with JSF, Spring, Hibernate application

Tags: performance, spring, hibernate, jsf, stress-testing

I'm working on web application developed by the following technologies (JSF, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL, MongoDB, Elasticsearch, Jetty server and Tomcat). I created a stress test that simulates the application use by one user. In test scenario, I'm running a stress test for 4 paralel users, and in the same time login as 5th user and measure system response time for certain activities. If we present a response time when stress time is not running as T, after 5 minutes of running stress test response time is ~2xT, after 30 minutes it's ~5xT, after 45 minutes it's ~10-15xT.

After 1 hour I stopped the tests, waited 25 minutes untill memory heap was less then 200mb and CPU use near 0%, and performance got better slightly, but not too much (~7T). 1 hour after the tests stopped nothing changed.

My PC has 8GB of RAM, and I run the application with -Xms512m -Xmx4092m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m, and according to what I found from JVisualVM and JProfiler, I don't think this is a memory leak issue. However, I'm not sure what else could be the problem. 
I hope someone could indicate what should be a possible reason for such a huge performance degradation or where should I look for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without some code or results from JProfiler etc. it is hard to see what is going on. You might have a problem with gc (too much or too little), transaction setup, wrong JDBC setup etc. hard to tell right now.

Comment: As @M. Deinum tells, check your application profiles and also opened DB transactions. You're actually checking the memory state but forget the problem could be in other layer.

Comment: I can't see any problem from these gc logs http://goo.gl/jqWufP, though I'm not an expert for it. Database connections seems to work fine and all connections are closed after the use. Memory is released after the test stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having analysed all aspects of the application I identified that Mojarra was the main reason for performance degradation. Ajax post response  time has been longer  while backend initialization remained the same after a stress tests. After moving from Mojarra 2.1.9 to 2.2.0, problems disappeared, and I believe that is related to the complexity of JSF pages and how Mojarra deals with big number of components on one page.